# php get data from another form using a different form

Tags: php

Is it possible to get data from another using a different form?
**I don't want to use one form**

```php
 <?php
     echo $_POST['2'];
     ?>
   <html>

   <head>
   </head>

   <body>
     <form method="post">
       <input type="submit" name="submit" />
     </form>
     <form method="post">
       <input type="text" name="2" />
     </form>
   </body>

   </html>
```

Comment: another what.. ?

Comment: Get data from another what?

Comment: From another form OR what?

Comment: yes another form

Comment: @Peter What if he posted the form on the first page and then redirected to the second page? He can assign the post array from the first page and pass it to the second page, right?

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible because browsers will only ever submit one form at a time (the one containing the clicked submit button, typically).

They can't possibly submit multiple forms at once because  each form has its own action and method attribute which determines the request to send.

Answer (score 1):

As @peter said, you can submit only one form at a time. But there are some workarounds for your needs.

### Method 1

Post your form to a php script(say `form_1_action.php`) and then store the form input in a **Session** variable.

```php
$_SESSION['form_data_1'] = $_POST;
```

Then you will be able to access it in different pages. Like,

```php
$_SESSION['form_data_1']['field_name']
```

### Method 2

Post your form to a php script(say `form_1_action.php`) and then store the form input in a **PHP** variable.

```php
$formData1 = $_POST;
```

Then you can use the data from the first form in the second form (the second form should be on the same file `form_1_action.php`) like

```html
<input name="name" value="{$formData1['field_name']"}>
```

> You should pass the data from the first form in a hidden field on the second form if you need it on the `form_2_action.php`.

### Method 3

Use **Javascript** to accomplish your requirements in a more userfriendly way.

Answer (score 0):

```
try using jquery to Prevent the other form from submiting and try updating the value using event listening of the first form and update that input. 
    $( '#Submit' ).click( function ( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();
var value = <?= $postedValue ?>;
$('input[name="input_name/2"]').val(value);
}
```